# Applications of transistor feedback

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, feedback

I saw the following circuit in an electronics exam. I think the feedback network consists of a transistor (M3) and a resistor (Rf) and the feedback type is current-current; Is this analysis correct?

I'm interested to know whether this feedback type has any applications in real life circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYMn3o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

**Edit**: The first circuit had a mistake which now is corrected. I've drawn the initial circuit with 2 CS stages.

Comment: All four types of feedback have applications in real life. Why else would they be taught? Just to torture you? As far as this circuit is concerned, are you sure it is correct? It appears to have positive feedback, unless I made a mistake.

Comment: @mkeith I don't remember the original question's details. I think you're true and the first stage should be a source follower.

Comment: mkeith, I think that M3 together with Rs will provide phase inversion. Hence, we have negative feedback.

Comment: I second that, feedback is negative. In the loop you have two SF and a CS thus gain is negative.

Comment: It was positive feedback when I made my comment. The circuit has since been edited, so now it is negative feedback. So that is all good and well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular circuit you are referring to might well be used in real life.

Think of your circuit as the output stage of some amplifier, where your load is RD2.

You can omit Rf entirely and be happy with it, but at a certain point you decide that you want to limit the current that flows in the output transistor, M2.

You add Rf and size it so that when your limit current is flowing into it, the voltage across it is the threshold voltage of M3, i.e. when output current is at the desired maximum, M3 starts to conduct.

What happens if M3 turns on? It pulls current from the Rs M1g node, pulling down that voltage, turning M1 a little more off, turning M2 a little more off, effectively limiting the output current.

Now, of course this loop might not be stable or fast enough for the circuit purposes, but at least in DC it is doing its job.

A little bit of amarcord:
[image]

image courtesy of https://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Semi/SEMI_8.html

Beware of the mighty uA741!

Have a look at the output side: see Q15? When too much current flows in R6 the transistor is turned on, steals some of Q14 base current and limits the output current. And Q21 is doing a similar trick, in a more convoluted way, by means of Q24-Q23 mirror.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't understand why "_This loop might not be stable or fast enough for the circuit purposes_"?

Comment: This is an entirely different topic. The point is: loops are good and they help you in keeping circuits standing but they can be not stable, i.e. start oscillating, which is bad. And usually a negative feedback loop slowers the system, making its transient response less prompt.

Comment: Also as you discussed DC characteristics of this circuit, another question came to my mind: Is the AC analysis of this circuit similar to ordinary resistive feedback networks? (e.g. finding the gain)

Comment: Well yes, but you do not have only resistive components. You can evaluate AC performances of that circuit only introducing the mosfets parasitic capacitances.